# Lemma 8.2.7 Tao Analysis 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following Lemma from Tao's Analysis 1

> Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ be a series of real numbers which is conditionally convergent, but not absolutely convergent. Define the sets $A_{+}\colon\!=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:a_{n}\geq 0\}$ and $A_{-}\colon\!=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:a_{n} < 0\}$. Thus $A_{+}\cup A_{-}=\mathbb{N}$ and $A_{+}\cap A_{-} = \phi$. Then both the series $\sum_{n\in A_{+}}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ are not absolutely convergent.

I am able to prove that both $A_{+}$ and $A_{-}$ must be countably infinite. Then, I proceed with proof by contradiction. The case when both $\sum_{n\in A_{+}}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ are absolutely convergent is easy. However, I am not sure about the case when (WLOG) $\sum_{n\in A_{+}}a_{n}$ is absolutely convergent but $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ is not. I am able to show that tail sum of the series $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ will eventually be small (which, if correct, would imply that $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, a contradiction). However, I am not sure if this is the correct approach. It seems to me that one should obtain a contradiction by showing that $\sup\big\{\sum_{n\in A}a_{n}: A\subseteq A_{-}, A\text{ finite}\big\}$ is finite which is the definition of absolute convergence for sums over arbitrary sets (Definition $8.2.4$ in the book). Could someone let me know the correct approach?

Comment: if $\sum_{n \in A_+} a_n < \infty$, then $\sum_{n \in A_{-}} |a_n| = \sum_{n \in A_{-}} -a_n = - \lim_N \sum_{n \le N, n \in A_{-}} a_n = \lim_N [-\sum_{n\le N} a_n + \sum_{n\le N, n \in A_+} a_n]$ converges.

Comment: The wording is a tiny bit confusing in the last sentence of the highlighted question.  I believe he is asserting that **neither** $\sum_{n\in A_+} a_n$ **nor** $\sum_{n\in A_+} a_n$ can be absolutely convergent.

Comment: Yes, that is what he means.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{n \in A_{+}} a_n$ is convergent  then so is $\sum_{n \in A_{-}} a_n$ because $\sum a_n$ is given to be convergent. Adding these two we see that $\sum_n |a_n| <\infty$ which contradicts the hypothesis.

I have used only the fact that sum and difference of two convergent series are convergent.

Comment: That $\sum_{n\in A_{-}}a_{n}$ is convergent is not immediately clear to me according to the definition of absolute convergence as stated in the question.

Comment: Let $b_n=\max \{a_n,0\}$ and $c_n =-\min \{a_n,0\}$. Then $a_n =b_n-c_n$. We know that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent. This implies that $\sum c_n$ is convergent. This means $\sum_{n \in A_{-}} a_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

First note  that both A<sup>+</sup> and A<sup>−</sup> are at most countable, because they are subsets of ℕ. I will restrict myself to both being countable. There is a bijeciton f: ℕ → A<sup>+</sup>. Likewise for A<sup>−</sup> there is g: ℕ → A<sup>−</sup>. 
In the second step we prove, that if one of the subseries is conditionally convergent it is also absolutely convergent. For every a<sub>n</sub> ∈ {n∈A<sup>+</sup>: a<sub>n</sub>} we know that a<sub>n</sub> = |a<sub>n</sub>|. If Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> a<sub>n</sub> is convergent and equal to L, Then L =  Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> |a<sub>n</sub>|. Thus Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> a<sub>n</sub> is also absolutely convergent. 
If A<sup>−</sup> is conditionally convergent with Σ<sub>n∈A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = K, then Σ<sub>n∈A−</sub> |a<sub>n</sub>| = <sub>0=i</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> |a<sub>g(i)</sub>| = <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> −a<sub>g(i)</sub> =  − <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>g(i)</sub> = − K. So this series is also absolutely convergent. 
Now we try a proof of the statement by contradiction. Assume that not both subseries need to be conditionally convergent. We have 2 main cases:
both are conditionally convergent and only one of them is conditionally convergent. 
case 1:
Both are conditionally convergent. Then both are also absolutely convergent.  By 8.2.6c  also Σ<sub>n∈A+∪A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = Σ<sub>n∈ℕ</sub> a<sub>n</sub>  is absolutely convergent, a contradiction . 
case 2: 
Assume to the contrary Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> a<sub>n</sub>  is conditionally convergent, again it is also absolute convergent. Sadly the prerequisites for P8.2.6c are not there, we know only of one subset that it is absolutely convergent.
Let Σ<sub>n∈A+∪A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = M and  Σ<sub>n∈A+</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = L. We make use of the bijections. I will only cover the case that both sets are countable, the cases with one of them finite are similar. Set up the bijection h : ℕ → A<sup>+</sup> ∪ A<sup>−</sup>
h(i)   =  f(i/2)             if i is even 
              g(⌊(i/2)⌋)     if i is odd
We have <sub>0=i</sub>Σ<sup>2N+1</sup> a<sub>h(i)</sub> = <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>N</sup> a<sub>f(i)</sub> + <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>N</sup> a<sub>g(i)</sub>  and when taking the limit of N to ∞ we get 
 <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>h(i)</sub> = <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>f(i)</sub> + <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>g(i)</sub>.  
So M = Σ<sub>n∈A+∪A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>h(i)</sub> = <sub>0</sub>Σ<sub>∞</sub> a<sub>f(i)</sub> + <sub>0</sub>Σ<sup>∞</sup> a<sub>g(i)</sub> = L + Σ<sub>n∈A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub>.
Reordered this gives Σ<sub>n∈A−</sub> a<sub>n</sub> = M − L, a finite value. So the other subseries is also conditionally convergent and we can refer back to case 1.
The case that only A<sup>−</sup> is conditionally convergent is symmetrical.

Comment: Sorry for the format. I wrote it down in Unicode + HTML for somewhere else.

Comment: no problem. I shall read and edit it when I get the time.